# Add sound effects at particular time in a Video file

Tags: java, android, ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg

I have a video file and I need to add multiple audio effects to it at particular time.

How can this be achieved ?

Using FFMPEG only audio can be merged with video file but how to add a small audio effect at particular time.

I tried the following way,

```
ffmpeg.exe -i video.mp4 -i audio.mp3 -map 0:v -map 1:a -c copy -y output.mp4
```

Is there any other open source or paid library to do this task?

Any kind of guidance will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Your question sounds good:) But I don't know if this [list of libraries](https://processing.org/reference/libraries/) helps or not. I have idea on appending an audio file to a video, but in your case I haven't tried.

Comment: Do you need to have these audio effect based on user input? Or is it just at a specific time in the video?

Comment: @Bojje Yes user will choose which audio effect he wants to add and at what time he would like to add.